# Кросс доменные запросы ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Мне нужно на WP забрать некие даныe с ОсStore

я пишу следующее :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://test.pp.ua/index.php?route=common/forBlog&callback=?",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data:  {'key': 1},
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

В файл который обращаюсь прописано следующее:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $data = array(
        'test1' => 12,
        'test2' => 'good'
    );
    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($data));
```

в Консоле мне выдает следующее: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и cамо тело с данными которые вернул файл
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как решить данную проблему?
Спасибо за уделенное время.

Comment: `function () {console.log(data);}` опечатка

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Все осталось по прежнему

Comment: @mydls1 вы ведь знаете, чем JSON отличается от JSONP?

Comment: По структуре насколько я знаю - ничем. jsonp вызывает колбэк функцию для обмена данными между разными доменами.  Наверно тех аспектов которые вы подразумеваете - я не знаю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Немного лирики.**

Формат [JSONP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) предполагает наличие оборачивающей функции вокруг передаваемых данных. Это позволяет использовать JSONP ответ, как полноценный JavaScript код и использовать его в теле тега `<script>`. Именно эта особенность и позволяет делать кросдоменные запросы.

Типичный пример ответа сервера в JSONP имеет вид:

```
callback123({"foo": "bar"});
```

В отличии от JSONP формат JSON не содержит оборачивающей функции и, строго говоря, не является полностью валидным JavaScript кодом. Типичный ответ сервера в JSON формате имеет вид:

```
{"foo": "bar"}
```

Если поместить такой ответ в тег `<script>` то JavaScript парсер должен выдать вам синтаксическую ошибку (`SyntaxError`).

---

**Теперь о вашей проблеме**

В клиентском коде вы требуете от сервера ответ в формате JSONP, а возвращаете обычный JSON. Это и вызывает проблему (причина описана выше).

Чтобы все заработало, достаточно отдавать валидный JSONP:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/javascript');

$data = array(
    'test1' => 12,
    'test2' => 'good'
);

$this->response->setOutput(sprintf(
    '%s(%s);',
    $this->request->get['callback'],
    json_encode($data)
));
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую , а вы можете дать ссылку на ресурс откуда информация про jsonp? С удовольствием ознакомлюсь.

Comment: @mydls1 https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: @mydls1, думаю для начала этого хватит. А вообще, в сети очень много информации по JSONP - достаточно просто поискать